# Engine temperature light always on

Tags: cooling-system, volvo-440

On my Volvo 440 (1992 1.8 LI with single point injection) the engine temperature warning light is always on. The gauge seems to work okay and fluctuates between low and middle (although it does seem to take a long time to move from the cold position).

What might the cause of this be?

Thanks.

Comment: Which year is your car and what engine does it have? They made this model between 87-97 and used six (6) different engines. It could be there are to separate temperature sensors for your engine temperature, one for the gauge and one for the idiot light ... knowing the year/engine will help us diagnose.

Comment: It is the 1992 1.8 litre LI model

Comment: With single point injection

Answer (score 2):

Check your coolant level in the reservoir. It may just be a low coolant warning light

Comment: Coolant level is fine

Answer (score 1):

Coolant level sensor might be bad.

Comment: Care to expound or give explanation?

Comment: On the cars I'm familiar with, the coolant level sensor trips the same light as the classic "overheating" sensor.  If the coolant level sensor fails it can cause your cooling system error light to come on even if the system is full and operating perfectly.  Sensor can be tested per the manual (normally continuity or resistance).

Comment: You should have put that into your answer to begin with ... while I didn't down vote you, I'm sure with this explanation it would not have been down voted in the first place.